# Does a CDN stale while revalidate cache update populate to all POPs?

Tags: cdn, cloudflare, vercel

When a background CDN cache is updated with fresh data from the origin, is only the cache for that specific POP updated or does this update populate through the whole CDN so that other POPs also serve the fresh data?

Comment: I'm sure it depends on the CDN vendor and their internal configurations.

Answer (score 1):

It does not. You can see how this behavior would be a scaling issue:

- Let's say the CDN you are using has `N` locations.
- If you revalidate the cache in one of them and the CDN can distribute this content across all edges, it must perform `(N-1)` requests. After all, you are telling all other edges to update.
- As `N` grows (more regions), the CDN will take more and more time to update all locations.